# PBKDF2 strong salt

Tags: authentication, cryptography, hash, pbkdf2

I want to use a strong authentication scheme, so I decided to use PBKDF2. I'm using PBKDF2 with SHA256 algorithm, 5000 iterations and I use username (which is full email address of user) as salt. 
So every user have a unique email, their email address is their identifier. So when they enter password, I'll use PBKDF2 with 5000 iteration and SHA256 algorithm to hash user's password.

Do you think it's good? Can you tell me if there is any security weakness on this hashing scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a weakness.  You should change the salt every time the user changes the password, and you cannot do that with your scheme.  An attacker who knows what the salt must be can mount a pre-computation attack, computing hashes for thousands of passwords.  Then, even if a user changes the password, the attacker probably already has it pre-computed.

The salt should come from a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator (CSPRNG).

Comment: Thank you for being clear, I understood. Can you point out some good CSPRNG algorithms?

Comment: It depends on the language.  Try Google for something like "CSPRNG PHP" or "CSPRNG Java".

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept answer after 10 min limit (it doesn't allow me to accept before that)

Comment: `/dev/urandom` on Linux/OSX, `CryptGenRandom()` on Windows.

Comment: @StephenTouset, Thank you! Anything for Mac ?

Comment: @BobBrown, but what if hashing supposed to be happening in user-side (javascript) ? What would you say then? Can I use hash of user+pass as salt? any ideas? User in client-side can't have salt before login and not having salt means, you can't generate same hash to send server for verification.

Comment: Although there are some user-side authentication algorithms, that's not one of them.  Whatever the client sends to the server *is* the password.  So, for a traditional password, hashing must take place on the client.  (And you need TLS to protect the password *en route*.)

Comment: @BobBrown, I'm trying to achieve "zero knowledge" protocol. I'm already using SSL.

Comment: Absolutely do not attempt to cobble together a zero-knowledge password protocol by yourself. If you must, use something like [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol), and use a preexisting implementation; it is, as I understand it, notoriously difficult to implement without unintentionally leaking information (for instance, through timing attacks).